# Java or C# sexagesimal/decimal conversion and vice versa, How is best?

Tags: c#, java, decimal, radix

I wish to use this when converting date/time formats and am unsure which way would be best. Should I convert to binary and then to the other format or are there other such methods already coded that I can access by using the appropriate said object library?

Your wise guidance would be greatly appreciated, THANKS. lol

Comment: please give a concrete example

Answer (score 0):

If you want a decimal representation of dates, in Java, you can use the [`getTime()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) method. In C#, you can use the [`Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) property.

Comment: Thanks Marcelo, I have decided to attempt the Java route due to it's multiplatform capabilities. From memory hasn't some part of this area been depracated?

Comment: @DOSrelic If you decided to go the Java way I would recommend to use the Joda-Time library http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article: [Sexagesimal Conversions in .Net](http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/04/30/sexagesimal-conversions-in-net/) There's written how to convert sexagesimal number to `double` and time (hours, minutes, seconds) to `double` and vice versa.

Comment: I believe that this post has a bug in ConvertDoubleToSexagesimal(), if you convert lets say 11˙11'31" after double conversion it returns 11˙11'-29". Simply add if (sec < 0) sec += 60; after